# How many paths are possible there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider following triangle
$$\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 & x_3 \\ 
x_4 & x_5 & x_6\\ 
x_7 & x_8 & x_9 & x_{10} \\
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} & x_{14} & x_{15}\\
x_{16} & x_{17} & x_{18} & x_{19} & x_{20} & x_{21}\\
\end{matrix}$$

Rules:

1. We start from $x_1$ and finish at $x_{21}$
2. We are only being able to move to the *right* and *down* (diagonal movements are not allowed)

How many paths are possible there?

Comment: Do you know Catalan numbers?

Comment: Yes, I've heard of them.

Comment: Google Dyck paths.

Answer (score 0):

See [Catalan numbers](https://brilliant.org/wiki/catalan-numbers/). This is a similar problem to the restricted path problem in the link.
Catalan number $$C_n = \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) {2n \choose n}$$

The proof is also mentioned in the link.